# Full Page Screenshots in Retina Quality using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, screenshot, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot

I'm struggling to find a solution to this, having tried many options.

My ideal goal is to be able to screenshot

- Grab a specific CSS element
- Grab the full height of the element (even if longer than the height of the page)
- Wait for any assets contained to have fully loaded
- Fast

**First attempt (using selenium-webdriver with chromedriver installed)**

Gemfile

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
```

App.rb

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome 
driver.get url
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

This works to a degree, but the screenshot is trimmed to a maximum height (which looks like a very old issue with Chromedriver https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294)

**Second attempt (using poltergeist to switch to phantomjs instead)**

Gemfile

```
gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
```

App.rb

```
require "capybara/dsl"
require "capybara/poltergeist"
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {
    # Raise JavaScript errors to Ruby
    js_errors: true,
    # Additional command line options for PhantomJS
    phantomjs_options: ['--ignore-ssl-errors=yes', '--ssl-protocol=any'],
  })
end
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist

class Screenshot
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Captures a screenshot of +url+ saving it to +path+.
  def capture(url, path)
    # Open page
    visit url

    if page.driver.status_code == 200
      page.driver.save_screenshot(path, :full => true)
      puts "screenshot saved"
    else
      # Handle error
      puts "there was a problem #{page.driver.status_code}"
    end
  end
end

screenshot = Screenshot.new
screenshot.capture url, "screenshot.png"
```

This has different problems,

- it captures the full length of the page
- webfonts are not embedded (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12132)
- retina is not available (https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10964)

**Third Attempt (using Capybara to try to take advantage of page.save_screenshot(path, :full => true))**

Gemfile

```
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'capybara'
```

App.rb

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require "capybara/dsl"

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.current_driver = :chrome

class Screenshot
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Captures a screenshot of +url+ saving it to +path+.
  def capture(url, path)
    # Open page
    visit url

    page.save_screenshot(path, :full => true)
    puts "screenshot saved"

  end
end

screenshot = Screenshot.new
screenshot.capture url, "screenshot.png"
```

Short version - this doesn't help

**Fourth Attempt (Using Watir)**

Gemfile

```
gem 'watir-webdriver'
```

App.rb

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new
b.goto url
b.screenshot.save 'screenshot.png'
```

This works (launches Firefox), but has the same issue over DevicePixelRatio for the ability to take a retina screenshot.

**Fifth attempt (back to using Chrome)**

App.rb

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto url
b.screenshot.save './tmp/watir.png'
```

Straight back to the cropped page issue.

Ideally I think that there *may* be a way to achieve this using the mobile emulation options of the latest ChromeDriver v2.12

> **Specifying Individual Device Attributes**
>
> It is also possible to enable Mobile Emulation by specifying
>   individual attributes. To enable Mobile Emulation this way, the
>   “mobileEmulation” dictionary can contain a “deviceMetrics” dictionary
>   and a “userAgent” string. The following device metrics must be
>   specified in the “deviceMetrics” dictionary: “width” - the width in
>   pixels of the device’s screen “height” - the height in pixels of the
>   device’s screen “pixelRatio” - the device’s pixel ratio

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation

But haven't managed to get it working.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question hasn't been answered by anyone else I thought I'd outline the solution that I used to get as close to the ideal as possible.

Ultimately until these issues with phantom JS are solved

- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10964
- https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12132

it appears the only driver capable of ensuring a full height screenshot is the Firefox driver.

Although it doesn't support retina using device pixels for my purposes I was able to transform using CSS the scale to 200% and the majority of elements (except bitmap images) are accurate.

For a working example of screen capturing a specific tweet at retina resolution in Ruby see here : https://github.com/chrism/twitter-screenshot